# How to get week number from excel sheet?

Tags: xlrd

Here its  not printing the week number,how to extract week number for each dates from excel sheet,it showing error like

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2015-08-24 00:00:00'
```

Here this is the line where iam getting error

```
print datetime.datetime(int(value[:4]),int(value[0:]),int(value[1:])).isocalendar()[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` is the complete String '2015-08-24 00:00:00'.
using `value='2015-08-24 00:00:00'` gives for your integers:

`>>> value='2015-08-24 00:00:00'`

`value[:4]` results in '2015'

`value[0:]` results in '2015-08-24 00:00:00'

`value[1:]` results in '015-08-24 00:00:00'

Instead of that you could use `value.split(' ').split('-')` to get 
`['2015', '08', '24']`.